# How to fetch font color from excel column values using openpyxl python library or any other python module

Tags: python, fonts, colors, extract, openpyxl

Logic. for example if col1 contains font color in green color then it will create new column and write green adjacent to that column values.

the output file will look like this

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: from openpyxl import load_workbook from openpyxl.styles import Font wb = load_workbook('abc.xlsx') sheet0 = wb['Tabelle1'] print(sheet0['B2'].font.color.rgb) o/p : Values must be of type <class 'str'> 
---------------------------------------------
please refer my github link . i have attached .ipynb file, image of the code and xlsx file which i am using.-----> 
https://github.com/cchtnn/firstProject/tree/master/Machine%20Learning/color_coding

Comment: If the cell has the default 'setting' color, i.e. you haven't manually assigned the color as black, typically known as 'Auto', then Null will be returned. To resolve this, use a 'Try/Catch', I use 'except AttributeError:'.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#colours) in the docs, you can use `font.color.rgb`. I suggest you read all of the [working with styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#working-with-styles) section of the docs.

So something like:

```
GREEN = 'green_hex_value'
style = wb['a1'].font
color = style.color.rgb
if color == GREEN:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for for your answer , I already used the logic that you mentioned.   please find the code below        .                            

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
wb = load_workbook('abc.xlsx')
sheet0 = wb['Tabelle1']
print(sheet0['B2'].font.color.rgb)

o/p : Values must be of type <class 'str'>

please refer my github link . i have attached .ipynb file, image of the code and xlsx file which i am using. https://github.com/cchtnn/firstProject/tree/master/Machine%20Learning/color_coding

Comment: Ah, I see. This isn't as straightforward as I first thought. You're using a theme colour which has no rgb value which can be seen via `cell.font.color`. You can check for the theme colours, or use colours that aren't part of the theme. Failing that, you could look for other libraries. And your `.fill.start_color.index` is giving you the fill colour, not the text colour. That's why it's incorrect.